# http to https redirection in WordPress site inside an AWS hosting website

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Https redirection is working fine for main website but having problem with the blog. Any of these doesn't work for me.

Test1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/blog/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Test2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) https://example.com/blog/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to configure this through WordPress config/settings as well

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've did that and it's happening too... but the problem is I am getting the website for both  `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`

If I use any further redirections it's showing redirected loop